# How to write a datetime format in FTL

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to create a expiration date translator depending on locale

**(Australia)**

Actual Date:
Ends 31 Jul, 2022 23:59:59 AEST.

Expected:
Ends 31 Jul 2022

**(France)**

Actual Date:
Expire le juil. 31, 2022

Expected:
Expire le 31 juil. 2022

My thought, unsure how to code it, please help

```
<#-- The string that comes from somewhere: -->
<#assign ExpiredOn = '(Actual)'>

<#setting date_format="(Unsure how to format it whichi need help)">
<#setting locale="(My region to be used)">
```

or

```
<#if locale = "">
  //use these format//
<#elseif locale= ""
  //use these format?
</#if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. When I try:

```
<#setting locale="fr">
<#assign expiryDate = "2022-07-31"?date("yyyy-MM-dd")>
Expire le ${expiryDate}
```

I get `Expire le 31 juil. 2022`.

Anyway, if you want a specific format, you can indeed use `<#setting date_format="...">`. Please refer to the [date time format settings documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#topic.dateTimeFormatSettings) for details. Patterns must be in Java's [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).