# Convert Date Time based on Locale

Tags: freemarker

Hello I am new to FTL Code and I am trying to re  format a date based on how a locale would display it.

The error I am getting: (Please look below for more info of the result we want)

The string doesn't match the expected date/time/date-time format. The string to parse was: "août 26, 2035". The expected format was: "MM dd, yyyy".
The nested reason given follows:
Unparseable date: "août 26, 2035"

```
<#assign locale = userPreferences.getLanguage()>
        my locale ${locale}<br>
        <#if locale = "en_AU">
            original = ${couponData.expiration}<br>
            <#assign expiryDate = couponData.expiration?date("dd MM, yyyy")?string("dd MM yyyy")>
            format ${expiryDate} <br>
            ${sys.declare("dateMonthYear", expiryDate)}
        <#elseif locale = "en_GB">
            original = ${couponData.expiration}<br>
            
            <#assign expiryDate = couponData.expiration?date("MM dd, yyyy")?string("dd MM yyyy")>
            format ${expiryDate} <br>
            ${sys.declare("dateMonthYear", expiryDate)}
        <#elseif locale = "fr_CA">
            original = ${couponData.expiration}<br>
            <#assign expiryDate = couponData.expiration?date("MMM dd, yyyy")?string("dd MM. yyyy")>
            format ${expiryDate} <br>
            ${sys.declare("dateMonthYear", expiryDate)}
        <#else>
            ${sys.declare("dateMonthYear", "${couponData.expiration}")}
        </#if>
```

CA_FR Source:

```
Ends Jul 31, 2022
Actual:

Expire le juil. 31, 2022
Expected:

Expire le 31 juil. 2022
```

EN_GB Source:

```
Ends Jul 31, 2022.
Actual:

Ends Jul 31, 2022.
Expected:

Ends 31 Jul 2022.
enter code here
```

EN_AU  Source:

Ends Jul 31, 2022.
Actual:

Ends 31 Jul, 2022.
Expected:

Ends 31 Jul 2022.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a datetime format in FTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73171792/how-to-write-a-datetime-format-in-ftl)

Comment: `<#setting date_format="...">` is missing

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue:

it seems in the string MM-DD-YY will format into something like 01/01/2022

Where as was proving three MMM-DD-YYYY will give me Jan 01, 2022

I can manipulate the dateformat inside the string also

```
<#setting locale="fr">
<#assign expirationDate = expiration?number_to_date?string("yyyy MMM. dd")>
```